# Download Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: visual-studio, download, visual-studio-2003

Hi I have an application developed in .NET 1.1  using Visual Studio 2003. I have to add some functionalities to it for which I need Visual Studio 2003 but unable to find it any where.  I would really appreciate if any of you could redirect me to a source where I can download Visual Studio 2003 ??

Thanks

sbmarya

Comment: it's a commercial product, you must buy it!

Answer (score 4):

You can look at to purchase it:
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Professional-English/dp/B00008I9K2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00008I9K2)

But, if you are using VS2005, for example, then this article may be helpful:
http://www.geekpedia.com/KB89_How-to-compile-into-.NET-1.1-using-Visual-Studio-2005-%28.NET-2.0%29.html

This may be a more complete article using VS2008:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2009/10/26/compiling-net-1-1-projects-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx

Comment: Forget amazon! On eBay you can find some realistic  offers at responsable prices.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you may try SharpDevelop version 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy an MSDN subscription, you can download it from MSDN subscriber downloads area.

Answer (score 0):

There is/was a Microsoft Visual Studio Express edition that may work for you. I'm not sure of whether it is licensed for commercial work though.